# Update / Insert

Tags: mysql

When I use this mysql statement I always will get a new row instead of updating?

```
INSERT INTO buyclick SET counter=1, link_id=3 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id),
  counter = counter + 1,
  link_id = 3
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `buyclick` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `clickeditem` (`link_id`),
  KEY `count` (`counter`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: might want to use UPDATE in that case. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: Next time, please format your code in a more readable manner from the beginning (did that for you here). And there is nothing in your INSERT query that could create a _duplicate_ – for `id`, you are not passing any value, and `link_id` and `counter` do not meet the requirements for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to work, since they are neither the primary key nor UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

You should also insert an `id`, so that the update is triggered. For example, if you already have a record with an id of `10`, do this:

```
INSERT INTO buyclick SET id=10, counter=1, link_id=3 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  counter = counter + 1,
  link_id = 3
```

Assuming that your table has a primary key `id`.

Comment: Thanks but ID is auto increment

Comment: Well you can either get the next auto increment ID and insert it manually or completely remove the auto increment property and take care of the ids yourself. In any case, there should be some `KEY` that is `DUPLICATE` for the query to work properly.